# Scrape PDFs inside viewer frame

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

(Complete begginer in web scraping here)
I'm trying to scrape the PDF from this webpage using python:

http://pesquisa.in.gov.br/imprensa/jsp/visualiza/index.jsp?jornal=3&pagina=1&data=31/03/1993

The problem is that the above URL points to the viewer (with date-page parameters), not the PDF file. I tried to inspect the html code to see the URL to the PDF directly, but could not.

any help on how to find the correct URL and implement a way to download them in python?

Edit:
I will later generalize this to other days and pages, the full list of day-page links can be found by searching for the relevant period here: http://portal.imprensanacional.gov.br/

Comment: The last link redirects to a JAVA error

Comment: Ok, I just corrected that, tks

Comment: Also, if you F12 on Chrome or Mozilla, you will find that the page is composed of many different divs one after another (for each text line, it seems). That could give you hints or help you to find a solution.

Comment: tryed that, did not help. I did find something: on chome, rightclicking on the PDF mage and selecting the "inspect (ctrl+shift+I)" option opens what seems like parameters for a direct link. But I don't understand them.

Comment: Unfortunately you would have to work a little bit on it [but not much]. You should 1. use urllib2 library - https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html to get the page content, 2. parse the content of the div tags using HTMLParser library - https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html and 3. put together the div tags content (python lists ".append()" method).